# 2Checkout INS notifications fail after disabling TLSv1.0

Tags: ssl, https

The last security scan we ran on our site indicated that having TLSv1.0 enabled as an SSL protocol was a security risk. After disabling TLSv1.0 on our site the 2Checkout INS notifications started to fail. Re-enabling TLSv1.0 solved the problem. (TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 have always been enabled.)

So we are left with a catch-22: if we leave TLSv1.0 enabled we fail our security scans but if we disable it we do not get any notifications coming through. I would like to know what SSL protocols the INS system support for sending notifications. Are there any workarounds/solutions? Sending requests unencrypted via port 80 is not an option for us.

Comment: @m.s. I don't understand why you deleted '2Checkout' from the title? Please help me understand.

Comment: please have a look at [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: @m.s. In this case I think it makes more sense to keep 2Checkout in the title. I've removed the corresponding tag.

Answer (score 0):

You could firewall an extra IP for a separate callback url, pointing to your callback script, and only allow 2Checkout's IPN IP to contact it, and enable TLSv1 in ssl_protocols on that vhost.